# add two numbers represented by linked list in scala

Tags: scala, singly-linked-list

I am new to scala and want to write a code that add two numbers represented by linked list in scala as per the below given example

Input:
  First List: 5->6->3  // represents number 365
  Second List: 8->4->2 //  represents number 248
Output
  Resultant list: 3->1->6  // represents number 613

I have implemented a code of mutable singly linked list in scala for adding,updating and inserting elements to linked list. Find my code below

```
    class SinglyLinkedList[A] extends ListADT[A] {
  private class Node(var data: A,var next: Node)
  private var head: Node = null
  def apply(index: Int): A = {
    require(index >= 0)
    var rover = head
    for (i <- 0 until index) rover = rover.next
    rover.data
  }
  def update(index: Int,data: A): Unit = {
    require(index >= 0)
    var rover = head
    for (i <- 0 until index) rover = rover.next
    rover.data = data
  }

  def insert(index: Int,data: A): Unit = {
    require(index >= 0)
    if(index == 0) {
      head = new Node(data, head)
    }
    else{
      var rover = head 
      for (i <- 0 until index-1) 
        rover = rover.next
        rover.next = new Node(data, rover.next)
    }
  }
  def remove(index: Int): A = {
    require(index >= 0)
    if(index == 0){
      val ret = head.data
      head = head.next
      ret
      } else {
   var rover = head 
      for (i <- 0 until index-1) rover = rover.next
        val ret = rover.next.data
        rover.next = rover.next.next
        ret
      }
  }


}
```

Can anyone let me know how I am going to perform the addition of two numbers represented by linked list.

Comment: What is your question? Which part are you stuck on? I suggest that you write in words the steps you need to solve the problem. Think about how you add numbers by hand.

Comment: Have you tried any method? How do you do addition by hand? Can you convert addition by hand into code?

Comment: what is your question? where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

How does addition works? I mean the addition on paper: one number under the other?

Let's try for 465 + 248

```
  465
+ 248
  ---
```

We start with the least significant digits: 5 + 8. But 5 + 8 = 13, so the result won't fit into a single digit. Which is why we do just like a teacher in preschool taught us: we leave the unit digit and carry the tens digit to the next column

```
   1
  465
+ 248
  ---
    3
```

Now tens. 6 + 4 + (carried) 1 = 11. Again, we leave 1 and carry 1 to the next column:

```
  11
  465
+ 248
  ---
   13
```

And the last column. 4 + 2 + 1 = 7.

```
  11
  465
+ 248
  ---
  713
```

Thus result is 713. If one these 2 numbers have more column or you would carry in the last addition, you could just rewrite remaining numbers.

With immutable liked list it would work the same way (I'll explain in a moment why I used immutable):

1. take both lists
2. take heads of both lists (if one of them is empty, you can just return the other as a result of addition)
3. add heads, and split the result into carry and current digit (carry would be 0 or 0, digit 0 to 9)
4. if there is `carry > 0` add list `carry :: Nil` to one of tails recursively
5. prepend digit to recursively added tails

You should end up with something like that:

```
val add: (List[Int], List[Int]) => List[Int] = {
  case (a :: as, b :: bs) => 
    val digit = (a + b) % 10
    val carry = (a + b) / 10
    if (carry > 0) digit :: add(add(as, carry :: Nil), bs)
    else digit :: add(as, bs)
  case (as, Nil)   => as
  case (Nil, bs) => bs
} 

add(5 :: 6 :: 4 :: Nil, 8 :: 4 :: 2 :: Nil) // 3 :: 1 :: 7 :: Nil
```

Now, if you would use mutable list it would get trickier. If you want to use mutable list you want to update one of them, right? Which one - first? Second? Both? Your algorithm might calculate the right result but butcher the input.

Let's say you always add the second list to the fist one, and you want to leave the second intact. If the second list is longer, and you would have to add some new places for digits, you have to copy all remaining segments (otherwise you could e.g. update one number in second list and change the first one). You would also have to handle the corner case with carry.

Quite counter-intuitive behavior - numbers are not mutable, and you want to represent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def add(a: List[Int], b: List[Int], o: Int): List[Int] = (a,b,o) match {
  case (x::xs, y::ys, d) =>
    val v = d + x + y
    (v%10)::add(xs, ys, v/10)
  case (Nil, Nil, 0) => Nil
  case (Nil, Nil, d) => d::Nil
  case (xs, Nil, d) => add(xs, 0::Nil, d)
  case (Nil, ys, d) => add(0::Nil, ys, d)
}
```